# how to control limit order condition with RSI?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi I am writing a script in Pinescript strategy a simple RSI strategy.

for instance, i want to open Long position  when price reach to Limit Price with rsi cross over overbought condition.

But problem is i using Limit order and this is future price so i don't know how to control this future price.

i can guess there is  way of control Limit price but struggle to implement.

if anyone help me much appreciate!

```
 //@version=5
strategy('RSI Strategy', overlay=true)
length = input(14)
overSold = input(20)
overBought = input(80)
price = close

vrsi = ta.rsi(price, length)

if not na(vrsi)
    if ta.crossover(vrsi, overSold)
        strategy.entry('RsiLE', strategy.long, limit= rsicrossoverbought)
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You can't use limit in [strategy.entry](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry)

You can use a trigger when Price with rsi cross over overbought condition.
Something like that:

```
if ta.crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
    strategy.close(
      'RsiLE',
      comment    = 'overBought')
```